# How to curve text in Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2010

I can't find how to create curved text in Word 2010 like you could in previous versions through WordArt. The point is to have the text baseline  follow some arc or circle.

In WordArt presets, I can only find stuff that formats each letter with shadows, etc. but not their position relative to each other. Can someone give me pointers?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Insert a WordArt object, then, in Drawing Tools - Format, look at Text Effects - Transform. Does that give you what you want?

If not, you can still get the old style. Save the file in Word 2003 format, and now when you choose Insert - WordArt, you'll see the legacy choices.

Reference: [Old Style Word Art in Word 2010?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/old-style-word-art-in-word-2010/2e5c2156-697c-4d0c-b39b-908e84f304bb)

Comment: Thanks that worked. Not sure how I missed "Transforms" in that menu. Anyways, it's pretty confusing on how to get there.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how:

1. Make a text box and put in the words you want
2. Click on the blue glowing *A* in the section WordArt Styles
3. Hover the mouse over Transform

You will be able to no make curved lines.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Word Art and typing in an individual letter and rotate it individually. So for instance, if you want to bend the word `PEOPLE`. Type in the letter <kbd>P</kbd> and rotate it, then type in the letter <kbd>E</kbd>, rotate it and place next to the letter <kbd>P</kbd>. Type in the next letter <kbd>O</kbd>, rotate it and place it next to previous 2 letters <kbd>P</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>. Continue with this with the other letters. Once completed, you will notice that the word `PEOPLE` are bend. It may take more of your time, but I find this method more effect and flexible as it gives the user more bending possibilities.