# Where is the Text Transform option for curving text in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I have looked at the following question: [How to curve text in Word 2010?](https://superuser.com/questions/208247/how-to-curve-text-in-word-2010)

Following the answer, I inserted a WordArt object.  The answer said to look at Text Effects → Transform, but I can't find that. I have Drawing Tools, Format Text, with options Text Direction, Align Text, and Create Text.

Where is "Transform"?

Comment: It would really help us help you if you stated your question - well - as a question and used full sentences. Just hit edit and give it another try.

Comment: @user99572_is_fine Done on Bob's behalf

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the WordArt object selected, then in the ribbon go to Drawing Tools → Format. In the *WordArt Styles* box you'll find *Text Effects* on the bottom right, and *Transform* at the bottom of that menu.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The tricky part is that the text effect button doesn't actually say "Text Effects." If you still go to the Drawing Tools and then Format, the Text Effects button is a letter A that has blue coloring around it. It's in the WordArt Styles section. If you hover the mouse over it, it says "Text Effects". If you click on it, the transform button is in the drop down menu.