# Using "transform" option in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word

One of your answers posted suggests I select "Word Art" object - I do not have this option on my ribbon! I want to be able to curve/transform words and need specific instructions how to do so given the options I have in my 2010 Word Program. After I have typed the text, how do I get to "transform" in the Text Effects option? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a "transform" option.  If you want to be able to resize and move the text as you wish, you can click the wordart object to select the object, and then you can rotate, resize and move the object where ever you wish, using the pick boxes and rotate icon that shows up at 12 o'clock when the object is selected.  Note this can be limited, dependent on text wrap of the object, but generally "In Front of Text" is good default choice to move it anywhere on the page.

I have a feeling you may be wanting is something more like the controls for 3D effects, which allow you to control more of the angle, tilt, depth, etc...   To use these you have to click to select the object, then if you go to the Format tab, and you choose Shape Effects >3D Rotation you can pick an approximation of the effect you want, and then you can fine tune within the 3D Format dialogue.

I can update with exact click by click instructions in 2010, if needed, but I suspect this should get you what you need.

Comment: Looks like my first sentence is incorrect... http://superuser.com/questions/364985/where-is-the-text-transform-option-for-curving-text-in-microsoft-word